# What is the file identifier for Fortran 90 in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to add vertical rules for Fortran code in VS code, with the following lines

```c
{
    "[fortran]":
    {
    "editor.rulers": [0, 1, 5, 6, 79, 120]
    },
}
```

in `settings.json`, I was able to make it work for `.f` files. However, the `.f90` files do not get any vertical lines. It seems to me that the [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) `[fortran]` is only for Fortran 77 code, but I can not  find any clue of such an identifier for Fortran 90 code. Could someone point it out to me?

By the way, I would need a separate vertical rule setting for Fortran 90 anyway, because the four leading vertical rules are only needed for Fortran 77 code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the extension Modern Fortran, then the ID for fortran language is changed, as shown in the contribution page of the extension.

```
ID                  Name        File extension  
FortranFreeForm     Fortran     .f90 .F90 .f95 .F95 .f03 .F03 .f08 .F08 .f18 .F18 .fpp .FPP .pf .PF
FortranFixedForm    Fortran77   .f .F .f77 .F77 .for .FOR
```

So if you want to set rulers for fixed form files, add this to your VSCode settings:

```
    "[FortranFixedForm]": {
        "editor.rulers": [1, 5, 6, 72, 80]
    },
    "[FortranFreeForm]": {
        "editor.rulers": [132,]
    },
```

> edit 2023 July: For older versions (<=v1.62), use this for fortran77. As [@lxlxlx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9331026/lxlxlx) suggests, in the latest Modern Fortran the ID has changed. (why are they changing this??)
>
> ```
>     "[fortran_fixed-form]": {
>         "editor.rulers": [1, 5, 6, 72, 80]
>     },
> ```

Comment: Thanks, however I think for Fortran 90, we only need a rule at 132 (the line length limit), right?

Comment: @zyy Yes you are right. For F90 maybe use "editor.rulers": [132]

Answer (score 1):

With v1.63 (and later version) of vscode, the `fortran_fixed-form` is already changed to `FortranFixedForm` instead.

So you (and for others newly-started searching for the answer) probably should use

```
"[FortranFixedForm]": {
    "editor.rulers": [1,5,6,72,80]
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this but possibly one of these settings helps:

```
 "files.associations": {

    "*.f90": "fortran",  // or the next
    // "fortran90": "fortran"
  },
```

if just using `fortran90` doesn't work as in

```
{
  "[fortran90]": {
    "editor.rulers":
      [0, 1, 5, 6, 79, 120]
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure for what reason, but the same script I had was not working suddenly. So I can not test your solution. I will let you know once I have it tried out.

Comment: I figured out, it is the extension [modern Fortran](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krvajalm.linter-gfortran) that is preventing the set of vertical lines, the other extension [Fortran](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gimly81.fortran) allows. However, the file extension association did not work.